# How to ensure rails ActiveRecord model always has one of many in a given state?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two ActiveRecord models; `Site` and `Template`.

A site `has_many` templates and must *always* have one active template, i.e. a site should not be without an active template, and should never be more than one template marked as active at one time.

How can I enforce this relationship within ActiveRecord within a Rails 5 app?

Comment: What do you expect if someone marks the second template as active? Should that dis-activate the first? Should that raise an error? How to activate another template if you cannot de-active templates?

Comment: If site.templates.present? then "action if ok" else "action if not ok" end (site.templates.any? may work too) (it's not activerecord related, just check where desired and redirect to the template new action if not ok)

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to look at this @spickermann. I think you'd have to mark the other templates non-active in that scenario, though that assumes an `active` attribute on the template, rather than a `active_template_id` attribute on the site. I've tried it both ways, and hit challenges with both, so wanted to leave the question open to any solution.

Answer (score 1):

I would add an `active` boolean column to the `Template` model.

To ensure that there is at least one active template add a custom validation to your `Template` model:

```
validate :at_least_one_active

def at_least_one_active
  return if active || site.templates.where(active: true).exist?
  errors.add(:active, 'at least one must be active') 
end
```

To ensure that is only one active template I would use an `after_save` callback in the `Template` model:

```
after_save :only_on_active

def only_one_active
  return unless active
  site.templates.where(active: true).where.not(id: id).update_all(active: false)
end
```

To ensure that you cannot delete the only `active` template add a `before_destroy` callback:

```
before_destroy :cannot_destroy_active_template

def cannot_destroy_active_template
  raise :abort if active
end
```

Comment: Thanks @spickermann. This works. It's actually what I had already, but I'd failed to recognise that I needed to `.reload` the pre-existing default in a spec, so I thought it wasn't working. FWIW `update_all` gives a deprecated warning in Rails 5, but can be replaced with `update`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest the following:

1. Add a column `active` to the templates. Add uniqueness validation to
   it within the site scope.
2. Add a custom validation to site,
   which will check if there is an active template.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Would the custom validation on `Site` handle the situation where the user destroys, or sets the `active` attribute to `false` on the template directly?

Comment: You will need some more custom validations or , which is better, before_delete and before_update hooks on template.

Answer (score 0):

You should add

```
class Site < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :active_template
  validate :active_template, presence: true
end
```

And add an active_template_id to your model's table. Also you can add has_one :active_site within your Template model, but nil should be allowed.